# How prove that a one of sides of the hexagon has a length greater than 1?

Tags: geometry

In convex hexagon three main diagonals have a length of $> 2$. How prove that a one of  sides of the hexagon has a length greater than 1?

Comment: Not a true proof, but the extremal case (as the most symmetric case it must be an extremum) is the regular hexagon, where the ratio between the diagonals and sides is exactly 2:1. A perturbation of this state will invariably increase one of the sides.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you consider opposite pairs of sides of the hexagon, they form a bow-tie with the two of the corresponding main diagonals.  Since there are three pairs of such main diagonals, one of them must intersect at an angle of at least $60^\circ$, at intersection point $O$.  Consider the triangles $ABO$ and $DEO$.  Since each diagonal has length at least two, in one of them, we will have $|AO| + |BO| > 2$.  Now the cosine rule in triangle $ABO$ will give:
$$|AB|^2 = |AO|^2 + |BO|^2 - 2 \cos \angle AOB |AO| |BO| \geq |AO|^2 + |BO|^2 - |AO||BO|,$$
which you can show is always at least 1.